# Cannot update twitter typeahead.js prefetch thumbprint after initial load

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using typeahead (0.10.1) in an app to return a list of clients using bloodhound prefetch. I can't work out how to update/reinitialise bloodhound with a new thumbprint so that after the new client is inserted it will use a new thumbprint and hence include the new client.

The system is ajax so I can't just change the name on refresh, I'm trying to pass it another thumbprint as per below in the reinitializeclient() but it's not working:

```
var clientthumbprint = "initialname";
var clients = new Bloodhound({ 
    limit: 5,
    prefetch:{
    url: '/urltofeed/',
    thumbprint:getthumbprint()
   },
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
  return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.label); 
},
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});
clients.initialize();

function reinitializeclient(newthumbprint){
  //This is called when a client is saved
  clientthumbprint = newthumprint;
  clients.initialize(); //this didn't work
}  

function getthumbprint(){
  return clientthumbprint;
}

$('#search_user').typeahead({
    minLength: 2,
  },
  {
   displayKey: 'label',
   source: clients.ttAdapter()
})
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: After updating my typeahead files using the pull request mentioned by @jharding, I can get it to reset, but not reinitialise.Using the following:

```
function initialize_clients(){
  clients = new Bloodhound({ 
    limit: 5,
    prefetch:{
      url: '/pathtojson/',
      thumbprint:getthumbprint()
    },
    datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.label); 
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
  });
  clients.initialize();
};  

function resetclients(){    
  clientthumbprint = 'somenewthumbprint';
  clients.reset();//this works - after running nothing will return in search
  initialize_clients();//this is not working
}  

function getthumbprint(){
   return clientthumbprint;
}
```

Comment: You can't reinitialize Bloodhounds right now, but that ability will exist in v0.10.2. Here's the related pull request: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/703

Comment: Great! I grabbed that pull request and updated my files with grunt as a test. I can get it to reset, but I don't seem to be able to reinitialise it:

Comment: Try passing `true` to the initialize method when reinitializing. I'm still working through what I want the API to be, if you have any thoughts, you should post them on the pull request.

Comment: @jharding It reinitialises if I pass through try, but it is still using the old data. clients.initialize(true);  -- Any ideas. Will post my thoughts to the pull request. essentially I'd love to be able to also specify which sources to prefetch again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably had an answer to this already but i thought i would add the code that worked for me

```
//This seems to refresh my prefetch data
clients.clearPrefetchCache();

//not sure whether setting to true does anything 
//though, but according to the bloodhound.js it should force a reinitialise
clients.initialize(true);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got my results from url as JSON data using prefetch,
and wanted to clear only prefetch data (as I need to clear it after adding some other data)

`clients.initialize(true);` method worked for me

Answer (score 1):

this always works for me to clear local/prefetched/remote data and reload it:

```
clients.clear();
clients.clearPrefetchCache();
clients.clearRemoteCache();
clients.initialize(true);
```

Comment: Thanks. This project seems to have been pretty much abandoned -- do you know of anyone who has picked it up for active development?

Comment: nope, I don't know if anyone has picked it up but I spent a few days dealing with that issue that is described here and all that matters for now is that I fixed the problems lol